# Add a MenuItem to Menu at specific position or group programmatically

Tags: android, menuitem, android-navigationview

I have a

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  app:menu="@menu/drawer"
/>
```

with the following menu items:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/main_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main"
    android:title="@string/app_name"/>

<group
    android:id="@+id/some_group"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/teams_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_teams"
    android:title="@string/teams"/>
```

Now I want to add an item either to the `some_group` or just below it.

I tried:

```
MenuItem mi = menu.add( R.id.soume_group, someId, NONE, "some name" );
```

or

```
MenuItem mi = menu.add( R.id.soume_group, someId, 2, "some name" );
```

but the items are added at the bottom of the menu.

How to fix my problem?

TIA

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `orderInCategory` to define the order

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main"
        android:orderInCategory="100"   
        android:title="@string/app_name"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/teams_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_teams"
        android:orderInCategory="1000"      
        android:title="@string/teams"/>
```

if you want to insert between `main_item` and `teams_item` you can use `orderInCategory` that is between

```
// 500 is between main_item(100) and teams_item(1000)
MenuItem mi = menu.add( NONE, someId, 500, "some name" );
```