# How can I merge two menus and sort them?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I have a Navigation Drawer menu with

```
nav_view.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_drawer)
```

[image]

Then I would like to put another submenu in between with

```
nav_view.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_drawer) 
nav_view.inflateMenu(R.menu.sub_drawer)
```

then looks like following

[image]

As you can see the special submenu is appende after quit. I owuld like to put it before Quit. Quit should be the last menu item..  as here

[image]

I seperated the menu.xml because I want to insert the second `R.menu.sub_drawer` from library level.. dynamic programatically..

**How?**

Comment: Any order that you need to do, can be changed in the menu xml that you are populating in your NavigationViewer, for example you can see here, https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

Comment: Is there a reason that they are separated in the first place?

Comment: @AhmedHegazy I want to insert `R.menu.sub_drawer` from library level.. dynamically

Comment: @JitendarM no xml, programatically

Comment: You can look at this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971541/add-a-menuitem-to-menu-at-specific-position-or-group-programmatically

Hope this helps!